Error when installing @twilio/conversations
When I'm installing in my react-native application @twilio/conversations and call any of it's methods, it crashed my app

I found the main reason. When I installed @twilio/conversations package, in its modals there were lots of unnecessary symbols so I just removed them, and patched those files.
